# How to calculate the sum of(1+a%m+a^2%m……+a^n%m)

Tags: algorithm

How to calculate the sum of `(1+a%m+a^2%m……+a^n%m)` where 
`m=k!, 1<=k<=12, n<=10^18`. How to Calculate this sum.
Using computer and the time limit is 3 sec.
Sorry about my mistake

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a maths question.

Comment: `m=k!.1<=k<=12.n<=10^1` ??

Comment: in a for(i=1; i<=n; i++) loop? ;-)

Comment: mathoverflow Mathemetic Mathematics ...Please check these stackexchange sites,And the tag gives me you are asking for algorithm .Make it in the Question title or in the @n content that you are asking the algorithm

Comment: This would be a ***very*** simple program/algorithm (see comment from @SamHolder, above), is that really what you want help with?  Or is there some additional/unobvious issue here?

Comment: Hint `(a+b)%m = (a%m +b%m)%m` this way you can reduce the summands. Than think about, if you really need to calculate each summand.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: One obvious issue is that the problem, as stated, requires adding up to 1,000,000,000,000,000,001 numbers in under 3 seconds. :-)

Comment: @NPE Ah, I see, the question needed editing to clarify the ranges.

Comment: @Ben No, technically this is not a Math problem, as Mathematics does not deal with compute time, only programming does that.

Comment: It's a geometric sum.  They have a simple closed form solution.  It takes about 30 nanoseconds to compute.

Comment: @DanielV - false. Notice the modulo and the large `n`.

Comment: Please Note the current question.I made a mistake just now.

Comment: I am assuming `a^n mod m` becomes periodic relatively fast for `m = k!, 1 <= k <= 12`. Have you tested this?

Comment: @IVlad I don't test it,and you can do it and find some results.

Comment: I see.  The point of having m=k! is so that it is unlikely that (a-1) is relatively prime to m, meaning that there will be no modular inverse to a-1.  That actually makes this an interesting problem.

Comment: @DanielV - yes, and the highest voted answer useless, sadly.

Comment: @IVlad They only have to form cycles for p^n <= k, you can reassemble the answer with the chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: nice problem, why closed?

Comment: @IVlad: Wouldn't it be reasonable to use the same idea as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18891223/1009831?

Comment: @EvgenyKluev - not sure. In its original form where the entire thing was asked `mod m`, yes. In this form (notice that there's no `mod m` for the entire sum), it wouldn't really help. I'm thinking there needs to be a pattern, or `mod m` is missing at the end. I assume the fact that `m` is a factorial should also be used in the solution.

Comment: @IVlad The link you give me is a simple version of this problem.It can't solve this problem.That problem using recursion to solve the problems

Answer (score 5):

```
1+a+a^2+...+a^n = (1+a+a^2+...+a^n)*(1-a)/(1-a) =
= (1 - a^(n+1))/(1-a)
```

In other words, your expression can be computed as:

```
(1 - a^(n+1))/(1-a) % m
```

Or, in programmatic form,

```
fmod((1-pow(a,n+1))/(1-a), m)
```

Comment: (+1) Awesome. Can you think of a reason `m` is restricted to being a factorial?

Comment: What if `1 - a` does not have a multiplicative inverse mod `m`? Using bignums will not be efficient for such a large `n`. This is nice, but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Would there not be numerical issues around `a=1`?

Comment: Yes, it would. But it can be computed as separate case (trivial, I might add)

Comment: Sorry, by "around 1" I mean "near 1" rather than "at 1" (assuming `a` is a floating-point number).

Comment: pow(a,n+1) will exceed 64-bit integer.. if you use biginteger, it will get very slow..

Comment: @NPE: I think single formula will still compute it with higher precision compared to summing up many imprecise numbers

Comment: -1 until you address the no multiplicative inverse case and bignums being too slow issues. Also, the problem has slightly changed now.

Comment: WTF! incredible that all of us are the same species..

Comment: Try running fmod on a number with 10^18*log10(a) digits in it.  It might take a bit longer than 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sum = 0;
 i = 0;
 while(i <= n){
 sum = sum + math.pow(a,i);
 i++;
 }
 result = sum % m;
```